# Angular 4: Providing data from inside a service to be used by components

Tags: angular

Here is my scenario:

I want to use a service to provide the results of an api call to me, without having to use the api get methods in the components. This is what I want to call inside the service:

```
private getData():Observable<Data>{
    const url = 'myUrl';
    return this.http.get<Data>(url).pipe(
  catchError(this.handleError<Data>('getData'))
);
```

Then:

```
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
 this.getData().subscribe(t => {
  this.Data = t;
  console.log(this.Data);
  });
}
```

However, when I call this:

```
retrieveData(): Data{
  return this.Data;
}
```

in the component, it comes back undefined. I know that it is a timing issue, but I am not clear on how I should approach this differently. Where should the call be so that I can use this? I am using this service across the whole app to maintain a single object for the purpose of previewing changes before an update call to the api.

EDIT: 
This is an example of how I tried the call, just to see if I could get the data first:

```
ngOnInit() {    
  console.log(this.service.retrieveData());
}
```

(inside a component used for altering the Data class object)

Another EDIT: The service is declared in app.module.ts

Aaaand one more thing I realized I didn't clarify. The constructor call above is in the service, not the component. The only thing the component should call is the retrieve method

Comment: where you are calling the `retrieveData` function and when

Comment: Of course it will return undefined, at least before the asynchronous http service call has completed. Just deal with the fact that it's undefined at the beginning. The best way to deal with that depends on the use case. We have no idea where you call this method and why.

Comment: @JBNizet I will be calling it to retrieve Data in every component that needs it, preferably in ngOnInit

Comment: You already retrieve the data in your constructor. That code should be in ngOnInit. If you want to log the data, put that in the callback passed to subscribe().

Comment: @JBNizet The goal was to see if I could access it at all, which is why the console.log in ngOnInit. that call returns undefined. I want to return the object, and use it in that component to display the data, use it in a form, etc.

Comment: Well, in the view, you can always access it, since it's a field of the component. Just be aware that it will be undefined for a short while, and decide what to do during that short moment. For example, don't display anything, using `<div *ngIf="Data"> show the data here</div>`.

Comment: It is not displaying anything. I just get an empty page. I understand the reasoning you presented, and it made sense, but it doesn't seem to work in this instance

Answer (score 0):

Better to check for undefined before your request gets completed.

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.getData().subscribe(t => {
      if (JSON.stringify(t) != {}) {
        this.Data = t;
        console.log(this.Data);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify(t) != {}`? That makes no sense. stringify returns a string. why would you compare a string with an empty object? What's the point of this check?

Comment: In order to check the api returns a not null response. Otherwise you will ended up having this.Data undefined. This might be the case. You need to assign the response to a variable once you get a valid response.

Comment: You can do this (typeof t != 'undefined')